# Java - Files appear to be the same using java.Scanner, but are not evaluated as being "equal"

Tags: java, encoding, diff, filereader

I have set up a JUnit test that is testing a method called `copy(File src, File dest)` that simply copies the contents of the `src` file to the `dest` file. I am using a Scanner to iterate over each file simultaneously (two different Scanners of course), and then comparing each Scanners `next()` with `.equals()`.

This test fails, telling me the files are not equal. But how can this be? The strings look identical when I print them, not to mention I did a `hex dump` of the files right after the call to `copy()` and those look identical as well. However, when I print each value of `next()` in bytes, I do indeed get different byte patterns. I am confused as to why this is happening, and what changes I can make to my code to account for this?

My thinking is that it has something to do with the encoding of the files, perhaps the encoding method used to create the files is different then the one used by `copy()` elsewhere in the program? Really not too sure, any help is appreciated! Here is what I am working with for the test unit:

```
// The @Rule and @Before blocks are used as set up helper methods for @Test.
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();

    private File f1, f2;

    @Before
    public void createTestData() throws IOException {
        f1 = tmp.newFile("src.txt");
        f2 = tmp.newFile("dest.txt");

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f1));
        out.write("This should generate some " +
                "test data that will be used in " +
                "the following method.");
        out.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void copyFileTest() throws FileNotFoundException, 
    Exception {
        try {
            copyFile(f1, f2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(f1);
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(f2);

        // FileReader is only used for debugging, to make sure the character
        // encoding is the same for both files.
        FileReader file1 = new FileReader(f1);
        FileReader file2 = new FileReader(f2);
        out.println("file 1 encoding: " +file1.getEncoding());
        out.println("file 2 encoding: " +file2.getEncoding());

        while (s1.hasNext() && s2.hasNext()) {
            String original = s1.next();
            String copy = s2.next();

            // These print out to be the same ...
            out.println("\ns1: " +original);
            out.println("s2: " +copy);

            // Nevertheless, this comparison fails!
            // These calls to getBytes() return different values.
            if (!(s1.equals(s2))) {
                out.println("\nComparison failed!! \ns1 in bytes: " +original.getBytes()+ 
                        "\ns2 in bytes: " +copy.getBytes());
                fail("The files are not equal.");
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my output:

```
file 1 encoding: UTF8
file 2 encoding: UTF8

s1: This
s2: This

Comparison failed!! 
s1 in bytes: [B@16f5b392
s2 in bytes: [B@5ce04204
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from the println where the compare fails?

Comment: If you actually open the files are they the same? Could it be new line or spaces problem?

Comment: @Kelly I provided the output.

@RNJ yes I can open them and they look the same. I can only open them during debugging though, as `JUnit` removes them after the test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Scanner` doesn't override `Object.equals()`, so it's comparing references, which in your case are not equal since you you have two separate `Scanner` objects.

Comment: Thanks GriffeyDog! Wow so all along I was passing the actual scanners instead of the tokens returned by `scanner.next()` huh? Rookie move :)

Comment: @Houdini Don't let it get to you. I suspected the .equals() but sometimes you need a more powerful tool than a unit test: another set of eyes; happens to all of us (even after 10+ years of coding).

Comment: Thanks Kelly, yeah a second pair of eyes is always welcome. Still smacking my forehead over that one but...moving on :)